# I can't install selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, installation

I want to install selenium. Ich have open the commandblock
I Set the command ,pip install selenium,.
Than comes this: WinError 5: access denied

I try to install selenium to use it.
Can anyone help me? Which setting i have to Chance that i get access?

Comment: maybe more error details should be better

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.